# Select all columns greater than some value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am new to mysql and I have structure like this

```
timestamp | Name | Total | Student1 | Student2 | Student3
20150911  | X    | 100   |       76 |       10 |       NA
20151111  | Y    | 70    |       NA |        0 |       23
```

Now I want to select with mysql query where at given 'timestamp'

- all student columns which have non-zero numbers
- all student columns which are NA
- all student columns which are zero

**Expected outcome**

- If I put 'non-zero' query , it should give names of column as ' Student1, Student2' for timestamp 20150911
- If I put 'zero' query , it should give names of column as () for timestamp 20150911
- If I put 'NA' query, it should give names of column as 'Student3' for timestamp 20150911

I have tried searching for such mixed selection but so far I am not successful. Most of answers are concentrating on row selection rather columns.

Comment: How many student columns do you have(variable or fixed number)? Anyway it looks like poor desing, for each new student you have to alter table

Comment: @lad2025 I have 15 columns right now. However I want to keep it flexible so that in future I don't need to worry. However maximum student columns can go is 30.

Comment: Because you can determine on a record level only whether to include that record in the resultset, not on a column basis. Pls define the expected outcome, so we can help with the query.

Comment: "I have structure like this". Yes. Fix that. See normalisation.

Comment: @Shadow, I have added expected outcome.

Comment: @lad2025, it is okay. At the end I will be concern about values at only one timestamp. I can ignore null values for newly added columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data structure is not normalized. But if you want to go this path use:

```
select sub.student
FROM (
  select t.timestamp,
    t.Name,
    t.Total,
    c.col AS student,
    case c.col
      when 'Student1' then Student1
      when 'Student2' then Student2
      when 'Student3' then Student3
      -- ...
    end as d
  from mytable t
  cross join
  (
    select 'Student1' as col
    union all select 'Student2'
    union all select 'Student3'
    -- ...
  ) c
) AS sub
WHERE sub.timestamp = '20150911'
  AND sub.d > 0;
  -- sub.d = 'NA'
  -- sub.d = 0
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a95730/5/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════════╗
║ student  ║
╠══════════╣
║ Student1 ║
║ Student2 ║
╚══════════╝
```

If you want comma separated result use:

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(sub.student ORDER BY sub.student) AS result
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a95730/8/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═══════════════════╗
║       result      ║
╠═══════════════════╣
║ Student1,Student2 ║
╚═══════════════════╝
```

Comment: Then can you suggest some good data structure for this kinds of queries ? I can change accordingly.

Comment: @Dexter This should be new question. For original question I provided answer. Anyway you should read about database normalization

Comment: @Dexter. Indeed, that's probably the subject of a new question (or an amendment to the existing question), but it's probably going to involve two tables - an events table, which holds the timestamp, and an event_participants table which holds the event_id and the ids of the participants. Obviously, name the tables as appropriate for your purposes.

Comment: @lad2025 . . . Your first `case` is unnecessary.  You can just use `c.col`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Funny I didn't see it earlier and do identity CASE, thanks :)