# Selecting columns with values ​greater than 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have only one row with a lot columns in my table. I want to select columns with values greater than zero.

```
WHERE (col_1 > 0) and ... (col_99 > 0)
```

It will be too long query, if i want to write all statements. Does it possible to write query with selecting columns with values > 0 ?

[image]

Comment: You need only columns with value > 0? Please tag the database also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select all columns greater than some value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33649045/select-all-columns-greater-than-some-value)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and their might be some shortcuts for doing this depending on the database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: What do you need exactly to select, please add details to explain your problem.

Comment: Well, you can select ROWS whose columns have specified caracteristics. You can't select columns, without using case..when statements in named fields. That's why I'm asking what's your goal exactly.

Comment: A SQL query has a fixed set of columns.  You cannot adjust the columns to be just those with particular values.  Dynamic SQL doesn't even work here because presumably there is a different set of columns for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bro flow the method its lengthy by works.

1. First you unpivot the data and select values where column value > 0
2. secondly Pivot again and you will get you desire result.

Comment: I think i get it. Thank you